# Is MKStoreKit still maintained and fully compatible to iOS 12?

Tags: ios, subscription, mkstorekit

I have been using an earlier version of [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit) within an older iOS app to manage the In-App Purchases. It worked quite well.

Now I am working on a new app which should support auto renewable subscriptions. I would like to use MKStoreKit again. However, the current version 6.1 of MKStoreKit was released 3 years ago. I wonder if it is still fully compatible to `StoreKit` in iOS 12.

Of course I could run a couple of tests myself, however bugs tend to hide in testing and show in production. So, does anyone currently use MKStoreKit 6.1 in production and tell me if is still a good solution or has any downsides/problems?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? I have the same question, need to add subscription to my old obj-c project.

Comment: Yes, I have added an answer to confirm that it still works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can can confirm that the MKStoreKit still works pretty well. However, I am not using it out of the box but made several adjustments to fit my custom needs.